# Why systematically mark record fields strict in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have read several times that it is good practice to systematically mark a record's fields *strict* in Haskell, e.g. instead of

```
data Foo = Foo { bar :: Bar, quux :: Quux }
```

do

```
data Foo = Foo { bar :: !Bar, quux :: !Quux}
```

For example here is a quote from [Haskell Programming from First Principles](http://haskellbook.com/), p.1134:

> A good rule to follow is lazy in the spine, strict in the leaves!

I (think I) understand what strictness is and what is the difference between the two. What I don't understand is why do the latter systematically?

Comment: could you add references to where you read that it is a good practice to do so `systematically`. thanks.

Comment: I would not do that _systematically_. In some cases, though, it is true that being strict in the leaves can help performance, especially for small-sized data types such as `Char,Int,Bool,()`. FWIW, I usually make everything lazy, and then try turning things stricter when profiling my code to see if something improves.

Comment: I tend to think record fields should be strict unless there's a reason to make them lazy, but the opposite position is defensible. One reason to make a field lazy is if its type is unknown (and therefore could be a function or similar).

Comment: From what I know you want strictness for "small" values such is these because unnecessary laziness leads to memory leaks. In many cases it is cheaper to evaluate the thunk and store the result than keep a lot of unnecessary thunks.

Comment: There's a lot of cargo-cult strictness out there. Occasionally it's good, but it usually leads to people like me filing bug reports that your types and functions are too strict.

Comment: @Carl, that's how I feel about `vinyl`. The (polymorphic!) strictness isn't good for laws. What sorts of bugs do you tend to see?

Comment: By the way, this "Lazy in the spine, strict in the leaves" business is extremely over-generalized. I'd go as far as to say that it's just wrong. There's really no substitute for thinking carefully about strictness and laziness in your data structure. Two things I will say: if something takes constant, logarithmic, or even polylogarithmic time, you should usually do it eagerly when possible. If it takes linear time or more, you should usually do it incrementally if possible.

Comment: @dfeuer everything has been of one of two forms. One is functions that go into an infinite loop because they're evaluating an argument before producing a constructor that was supposed to be guarding infinite corecursion. The other has been cases where I passed `undefined` to an over-general api, knowing it wouldn't be used, then discovered it was being evaluated strictly for some reason. The latter bit everyone using `containers` when it was made more strict unnecessarily in a minor release about 8-10 years back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A common rule of thumb is to make data structures strict when:

- You expect to strictly traverse the whole thing and retain it, so there’s no point in the overhead of laziness; or
- The fields are “small”—less than or equal to the size of a pointer—and you’d like the compiler to unbox them to avoid unnecessary indirections. (`-funbox-small-strict-fields` is on by default since GHC 7.7.)

This tends to be roughly the same as “lazy in the spine, strict in the leaves” in practice, because data structures often benefit from being lazy but their *contents* often don’t.

Doing this “systematically” is a naïve way to help avoid space leaks—for example, if you do repeated modification of a data structure (such as an accumulator) without forcing the value in the meantime:

```
ghci> data Lazy = Lazy { lazyField :: Int } deriving (Show)

ghci> data Strict = Strict { strictField :: !Int } deriving (Show)

ghci> modifyLazy (Lazy field) = Lazy { lazyField = field + 1 }

ghci> modifyStrict (Strict field) = Strict { strictField = field + 1 }

ghci> lazy = iterate modifyLazy (Lazy 0) !! 1000000

ghci> strict = iterate modifyStrict (Strict 0) !! 1000000

ghci> :set +s

ghci> lazy
Lazy {lazyField = 1000000}
(0.76 secs, 251,792,080 bytes)

ghci> strict
Strict {strictField = 1000000}
(0.52 secs, 178,173,544 bytes)
```

The lazy version builds up a chain of thunks before forcing it; the strict version keeps the `Int` field fully evaluated at each step. A similar thing happens with `modifyIORef` (lazy) and `modifyIORef'` (strict).

It’s mostly pointless to add a strictness annotation on a field with a type that’s non-strict, for example, `field :: ![Int]` only ensures that the *first* `(:)` or `[]` constructor is forced; it doesn’t make the whole list strict. If you need that, you probably want a strict sequence type like `Data.Vector`. And it’s generally inadvisable to make a polymorphic field strict, as in `data Foo a = Foo … !a …`, because someone who uses the type might expect to be able to rely on laziness there—for example, in an algorithm that uses cycles (“tying the knot”)—and it’s annoying to have to wrap a type in an extra constructor like `data Lazy a = Lazy a` to regain laziness. Laziness also plays better with equational reasoning—although in practice we often use “fast and loose” equational reasoning that ignores strictness and non-total functions.

Ultimately, the only way to decide whether something should be lazy or strict is to consider the semantics you need for your particular application, and add judicious strictness (bangs on fields, `BangPatterns`, `seq`, strict functions like `modifyIORef'`) after profiling if you encounter performance problems or space leaks.

Comment: My question stemmed from the fact I *never* had to worry about it and as I said, I have been writing Haskell for years. I suspect my performance requirements might not be high enough to notice the problems hence fix it.

Comment: @insitu: Try running your code with profiling enabled some time, and check out the heap graph. If it looks like `/|`, building a lot over the course of the program’s execution (i.e., much more than the size of the data you’re working with) and only dropping at the end, then you may have a space leak—which you can then locate using type & retainer profiling. It won’t usually cause serious performance issues for short-lived programs, unless peak memory usage is very high; GHC Haskell performance is generally very good, but it really depends on the application.

Comment: Thanks. I usually write long-running server applications (e.g. backend) and do use GHC profiling, and never had this problem, or at least never noticed it.

Comment: @JonPurdy Could you give a link to this _type & retainer_ profiling technique? I never heard this. Is a different name for this: http://neilmitchell.blogspot.sg/2015/09/detecting-space-leaks.html

Comment: @Shersh: The [GHC Users Guide section on profiling](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html) has lists of compiler and runtime options, including `-hy` for type-based memory profiling and `-hr` for retainer profiling.